# Browser: Identifier input has already been declared, but only on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, java, wordpress

I am making a search form that expands, I am doing exactly this ... 
https://codepen.io/MilanMilosev/pen/JdgRpB

I made a simple html and it works, but I want to put it in a wordpress, with an online store, but when I put all the code, the console marks the error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'input' has already been declared

And this is the javascript used

```
const input = document.getElementById ("search-input");
const searchBtn = document.getElementById ("search-btn");

const expand = () => {
   searchBtn.classList.toggle ("close");
   input.classList.toggle ("square");
};

searchBtn.addEventListener ("click", expand);
```

Anyone have an idea why it happened?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it is a well-formed question that meets the criteria. Sometimes it can be hard to search for a relevant answer when you don't know what question you are asking. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the usage of a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and its being redeclared in the line:

```
const input = document.getElementById ("search-input");
```

Another instance of `const` input already exists per the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'input' has already been declared

You simply need to rename the variable as you can not redeclare the constant in the same scope. `let` will allow for redefining ( changing the value ), but you should never need to redeclare a variable.